# How to set environment variables in .bashrc file

Tags: bash, shell

I am new in scripting and trying to understand some scripts written by others in our company--

```
# Update .bashrc of vnom user
sudo su - ${ora_install_user} -c "echo '
VNOM_HOME=${gsm_home}; export VNOM_HOME
PATH=\$PATH:\$VNOM_HOME/bin; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$VNOM_HOME/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH'  >> ~/.bashrc"
```

I could understand what it is doing, that is, setting an environment variable VNOM_HOME and appending it to the PATH environment variable.

However not sure of this `"PATH=\\$PATH:\$VNOM_HOME/bin"` , cant I just put `"PATH=$PATH:\$VNOM_HOME/bin"` leaving the first backslash after `"PATH="`?

Also--

```
 # Update /etc/oratab
sudo su - ${ora_install_user} -c "echo '
gsm:${gsm_home}:N'  >> /etc/oratab"
```

I got most of it, but why is the ":N" required

One more doubt, why do we have "gsm:${gsm_home}" and not "gsm=${gsm_home}".
What is the difference?

Comment: The backslashes in PATH=\$PATH:\$VNOM_HOME/bin are escaping the dollar signs to prevent parameter expansion. The ':N' in gsm:${gsm_home}:N in the /etc/oratab file indicates that the oracle instance referenced by the gsm:${gsn_home} (oracle SID/oracle home directory) should NOT be started automatically on system startup.

Comment: Environment variables should be set in `.bash_profile`, so that regular interactive shells can simply *inherit* their values from (ultimately) your initial login shell.

Comment: @user496934 : Actually, this script is a pretty bizarre way to "automatically" edit the ~/.bashrc.  Run it several time, and your .bashrc will grow bigger and bigger. I don't see why anybody would seriously want to use such a script.

Comment: @user1934428 I think the intent is to run it only once per user/machine.

Comment: @chepner : Perhaps, though as user, I would be upset if someone modifies my configuration files under the hood. A cleaner solution would be to provide system-wide configurations in a separate file (maybe inside `/etc`) and ask each user to add _source_ this file from inside `.bashrc`. In this way, maintaining this configuration would also be easier (think about the case that directories inside the PATH are supposed to change).

Comment: thanks for all your comments, very helpful. I just posted one more doubt.